# how to set the value in DropDownListFor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

There is CreatePage views:

```
 <select name='Fields[0].TypeFields' onchange='addElement(this);'>
     <option>Type of field</option>
     <option value='1'>One of the list</option>
     <option value='2'>several of the list</option>
     <option value='3'>Drop-down list</option>
     <option value='4'>Text-string</option>
     <option value='5'>Text-paragraph</option>
  </select>
<input type="submit" value="Save">
```

Form expandable using onchange='addElement(this), therefore name='Fields[0].TypeFields'.
Pressing the button sends the value to the database. If "One of the list" is selected then value='1' is sent.
But when I go to the form edit page, the value is set to default "Type of field".

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Fields[i].TypeFields, new SelectListItem[]
  {
    new SelectListItem(){ Text="Type of field", Disabled = false},
    new SelectListItem(){ Text="One of the list", Value = "1"},
    new SelectListItem(){ Text="Several of the list", Value = "2"},
    new SelectListItem(){ Text="Drop-down lis", Value = "3"},
    new SelectListItem(){ Text="Text-string", Value = "4"},
    new SelectListItem(){ Text="Text-paragraph", Value = "5"}},
    new { @onchange = "addElement(this);" })
```

And I need if selected '1' was chosen "One of the list". Maybe I chose a bad way.

```
 public class Field
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string TypeFields { get; set; }

            //other properties

            public int? NewFormId { get; set; }
            public virtual NewForm NewForm { get; set; }
        }
  public class NewForm
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }

             //other properties

            public virtual List<Field> Fields { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: I think you need to use `ViewBag` and set `Selected = true` setting for second option, then pass the `ViewBag` value into the dropdownlist helper instead of using `SelectListItem` array inside view page.

Answer (score 0):

As you say this is the hard way. İf you have 100 fields you can't add them like this :)  Fill a view bag and give as an data source. You can refer here: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/different-ways-bind-the-value-to-razor-dropdownlist-in-aspnet-mvc5/